# angular-google-map in tabs

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

First off, let me mention that I have seen many questions like these and proposed solutions, although I have found none that actually resolve my issue. Perhaps I did not implement something correctly or there is a solution which I have not found/tried.

I have an angular app and am using the git angular-google-maps directive.

My map is in a tabbed view and only shows up when the wizard/tab is showing the second div element. I realize that this is a google api issue where due to the element being hidden, the map is not initialised when the div is finally shown. It only begins to show/work when i resize the page or open the console, pressing F12 (in chrome).

Here is a [fiddle to illustrate my problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/dOMKgE?p=preview).

***HTML***
*Here is my html, this is inside a tab element built with divs.*

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="hide-map">
      <ui-gmap-google-map
         id="map-canvas"
         center="map.center"
         zoom="map.zoom"
         draggable="true"
         events="map.events">
      </ui-gmap-google-map>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
   <div id="pano" style=" height: 400px;">
</div>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
angular.module('ngPortalApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $log, googleMapService, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {
    $log.log('myCtrl');

    Init();

    function Init() {
      $scope.data = {};

      googleMapService.getData().then(function (result) {

        $scope.latc = result.lat;
        $scope.longc = result.lng;

        console.log("controller got data!");
        console.log(result);

        angular.extend($scope, {
          map: {
            center: {
              latitude: $scope.latc,
              longitude: $scope.longc
            },
            options: {
              maxZoom: 17,
              minZoom: 17
            },
            zoom: 17,
            events: {
              showMap: function (map){
                map.refresh();
              },
              projection_changed: function (map, eventName, originalEventArgs) {
                var Location = new google.maps.LatLng($scope.map.center.latitude, $scope.map.center.longitude);
                var panoramaOptions = {
                  position: Location,
                  pov: {
                    heading: 30,
                    pitch: 5,
                  }
                };

                var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
                map.setStreetView(panorama);



              }
            }
          }


        });
      })

    }

  });
```

Any solutions/advice for this? I have tried using ng-if to set and check for an activetab scope value, I have tied with ng-class and I have tried various events in the map scope but I am unsure how to actually call a map event such as map.refresh() which should work.
Thanks in advance for any help in resolving my fiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue by switching to using a different directive, namely simpler seeming, especially for street-view implementations. ngMap.

I have successfully and easily resolved the tabbing issue by calling a refresh function on my tab "next" ng-click which occurs in a div. There were some changes in the controller needed as well, namely a push/event had to be used in order to relay the map details upon refreshing.

***HTML***

```
<map zoom="20" center={{coords}} >
   <marker position={{coords}}>
   </marker>
   <street-view-panorama
      click-to-go="false"
      disable-default-u-i="false"
      disable-double-click-zoom="false"
      position={{coords}}
      pov="{heading:90, pitch: 0}"
      scrollwheel="false"
      enable-close-button="true"
      visible="true">
  </street-view-panorama>
</map>
```

***CONTROLLER***

```
$scope.reRenderMap = function() {
      $timeout(function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.maps, function(index) {
          google.maps.event.trigger(index, 'resize');
        });
      }, 200);
    }
    $scope.maps = [];
    $scope.$on('mapInitialized', function(evt, evtMap) {
      $scope.maps.push(evtMap);
    });
```

If anyone has the same issue please refer to the following fiddle and stack:

[Stack Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32371691/use-ngmap-with-tabset-only-the-first-tab-will-be-initiated)

[Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/s3yPC1ZQE5c8jZoqCmbf?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Using your fiddle as example.

The problem is that long and lat are not set when the map is `refreshed`.

The `refresh` parameter which is executed as a function within the ng map directive expects an object with `longitude` and `latitude` in it.

Without change the ng map directive, the only method I can think of to trigger a refresh would be to create a function that returns a unique value (with the previous long and lat).

In this example, I'm using a date time value to hold when the map was last updated (just to make it different from the previous value)

http://plnkr.co/edit/sIIWZcsa7WrCHuhHp3XE?p=preview

```
angular.module('demo', ['google-maps'])

.factory('demo', function($timeout, $q) {

})

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, demo) {

  $scope.activeTab = 1;
  $scope.lastUpdated = new Date();

  $scope.map = {};

  $scope.map.zoom = 4;

  // default center point
  $scope.map.center = {
      latitude: 45,
      longitude: -73,
      refresh:0
  };

  $scope.refresh = function(){
      return  {
        lastUpdated : $scope.lastUpdated,
        latitude : $scope.map.center.latitude,
        longitude : $scope.map.center.longitude
      }
  },

  $scope.$watch("activeTab",function(v) {
    if (v==2) $scope.lastUpdated = new Date();
  });

});
```

In this scenario, the map is refreshed each time tab==2.  You could change this to be once-only.

I'm sure there's a better option by fixing the ng map directive, but this should do you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however the map doesnt load up the very first time you load it....I can see what you did and I did try to implement as well but im afraid its not working or I cannot seem to get this method to work either. The fiddle doesnt load up the map on switching tabs, but after you initialise it, then you can switch back and worth without problems.